# In line variables in Python 3

Tags: python

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a+b
```

and

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
    print(b)
    a = b
    b = a+b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one computes all the new values before updating `a` and `b`. The second one computes and updates `a` before computing and updating `b`. The second one will give incorrect results because of that.

[Here's part of a good talk](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go?t=34m2s) by [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) where he talks about updating multiple state variables at once.

Answer (score 3):

Simultaneous:

```
a = 1
b = 3
a, b = b, a+b
# a: 3; b: 1+3
```

Sequential:

```
a = 1
b = 3
a = b
# a: 3; b: 3
b = a+b
# a: 3; b: 3+3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand to avoid a temporary variable. In many traditional languages, you had to do

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = b + tmp
```